# Replcae \n using sed with new line

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

pem
Whenever i use this key file to try to log in gives me error "Load key "abc.pem": invalid format"
My file looks like this, its not the complete key file just a part of it, so i need to replace charater \n with new line. Please help

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAlyOrvR1uMCc+cPwWJ6dIFg0AvPdtOxJuKU13cC4XZVOBHESf **\n** 31kmTp+GiKYLZ/0RhLDHqYCXqGVtM1v3OR7ccpktxNDzlNb0g5pV7dSjeaFOcJde\nix7q0J9WLeSPCHK7GtcrjMzNZU12Ifiu3BQ4ulSCu6N7SQGK/WGKzsACiWyij7Rm **\n** CLqR96Efu8+hMubshuGeHsnYdkAoiVoqtVofehILQnFwtllphggqPGQ3olx3/ygS\nTMWb+rS0cGffLGWOWNWP17xolvxuDnfWNjdYbQ2KeT8r9jzl6A/f9qszh5buwFoA\nT7Zsqbfcw/8sNepxRNeQMrwVzN/3s01v18d63QIDAQABAoIBAD3UD9uLgJoeU8Lw **\n** vTd3jVvH8fdb2MmDnqEy2ZuAn32KDZU81ZIO7EbZp7WbB6uAsXvwvZ0vx9rRszyB\ncL9jSpdu5nRPbnYDAYAc0O48QKvvOyGAKuMKwNCbfivEBmdUWAqA34X3+kZoy9zV\n2OKbOyGulNSh6jtRcER7dMdjcSY6McgzP2oZNfe6eRpPFNszV9lQd/6A/2BVzBXg\nBuhh/kf2ScVskleHRSQgaWiImN2GrerYmwDnmz7qVdReDjxfvAUnKVoGMnqawHHM\nYXvrzx47+UnEukJ1y48bbIzxXibjThfLC99MeS3JJuUvjpWeSc/Ss6+sHRcwhWiL\ns0D109kCgYEA5nk/9K75TCUzG+61ihtYgQ/XY0VO0Yb9D8D8o/rnFCmpbMVJf9kP
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: this has nothing to do with programming and is off-topic here

Comment: Wow! Seeing `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` on a public website is really weird. Thanks for the thrill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo 'a\nb\nc' | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved it couple of days back with same method

echo 'a\nb\nc' | sed 's|\\n|\n|g'
a
b
c